# Disable auto serializations for Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, serialization

Is is possible to disable the auto serialization when using spring mvc 3?

We have switched to using spring mvc but the serialization is already done so we don't want to use the auto serialization. Is it possible to disable that functionality and make spring just return the string as is?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 @ResponseBody
 public ResponseEntity<String> justReturnMyResponse() {
     return new ResponseEntity<String>(getAllreadySerializedObject(), HttpStatus.OK);;
 }

 String getAllreadySerializedObject(){
       // Some special serialization
       ....
       return jsonizedString;
 }
```

The above code serialize the String one more time, which isn't necessarily because it has already been serialized.

Comment: What spring feature "auto serialization" do you exactly points?

Comment: I'm referring the @ResponseBody. I've updated my question to try to be clearer. I just want to return the raw String value which is already serialized.

Comment: `getAllreadySerializedObject()` returns a JSON string no?

Comment: Yes it returns an already jsonized object.

Comment: If you want to get that JSON string "as is" then why don't you just return it instead of returning `ResponseEntity`

Comment: By "as is" do you mean that the string in your controller contains some specific characters that is not sent to your webpage? Such specific characters include `<` and `>`?

Comment: The problem is that I have to do for example: $.parseJSON($.parseJSON(returnVal)) to get the actual value.

Comment: If `returnVal` is a java object serialized as a json in the back end (means its a valid json), parsing it in the front end using jquery's `$.parseJSON` won't give you any problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41247/discussion-between-gizm0-and-onepotato)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did find a solution or something after some testing and reading, but I guess all those purist will scream in pain. The problem is that spring automatic sets the `@RequestMapping(produces="application/json")` but if I change to `@RequestMapping(produces="plain/text")` it works without having to do two deserializations .

Here is the new code with my fix:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "plain/text")
 @ResponseBody
 public ResponseEntity<String> justReturnMyResponse() {
     return new ResponseEntity<String>(getAllreadySerializedObject(), HttpStatus.OK);;
 }

 String getAllreadySerializedObject(){
       // Some special serialization
       ....
       return jsonizedString;
 }
```